# SQLAlchemy insert values into reflected table results in NULL entries all across

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The following code results in None () across the row in every attempt. The `query.values()` code below is just a shortened line so as to keep things less complicated. Additionally I have problems inserting a dict as JSON in the address fields but that's another question.

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.customers (
    id SERIAL,
    email character varying(255)  NULL,
    name character varying(255)  NULL,
    phone character varying(16)  NULL,
    address jsonb  NULL,
    shipping jsonb  NULL,
    currency character varying(3)  NULL,
    metadata jsonb[]  NULL,
    created bigint  NULL,
    uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);
```

```python
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# Create engine, metadata, & session
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@database/db', future=True)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
session = Session(engine)

# Create Table
customers = Table('customers', metadata, autoload_with=engine)

query = customers.insert()
query.values(email="test@test.com", \
             name="testy testarosa", \
             phone="+12125551212", \
             address='{"city": "Cities", "street": "123 Main St", \
                        "state": "CA", "zip": "10001"}')


session.execute(query)
session.commit()
session.close()

# Now to see results
stmt = text("SELECT * FROM customers")
response = session.execute(stmt)

for result in response:
    print(result)

# Results in None in the fields I explicitly attempted 
(1, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1, None, None, None, None, UUID('9112a420-aa36-4498-bb56-d4129682681c'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `query.values()` returns a new [insert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert) instance, rather than modifying the existing instance in-place.  This return value must be assigned to a variable otherwise it will have no effect.

You could build the insert iteratively

```
query = customers.insert()
query = query.values(...)
session.execute(query)
```

or *chain* the calls as [Karolus K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5677298/karolos-k) suggests in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67945839/5320906).

```
query = customers.insert().values(...)
```

Regarding the `address` column, you are inserting a dict already serialised as JSON.  This value gets serialised again during insertion, so the value in the database ends up looking like this:

```sql
test# select address from customers;
                                                       address                                                        
══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 "{\"city\": \"Cities\", \"street\": \"123 Main St\",                         \"state\": \"CA\", \"zip\": \"10001\"}"
(1 row)
```

and is not amenable to being queried as a JSON object (because it's a JSONified *string*)

```sql
test# select address->'state' AS state from customers;
 state 
═══════
 ¤
(1 row)
```

You might find it better to pass the raw dict instead, resulting in this value being stored in the database:

```sql
test# select address from customers;
                                  address                                   
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 {"zip": "10001", "city": "Cities", "state": "CA", "street": "123 Main St"}
(1 row)
```

which is amenable to being queried as a JSON object:

```sql
test# select address->'state' AS state from customers;
 state 
═══════
 "CA"
(1 row)
```

Comment: You know I tried that but only after `session.add(query)` which results in `Class 'sqlalchemy.sql.dml.Insert' is not mapped` - no realizing skipping the `session.add()` makes it work. Then how do I `session.add_all(queries)` and avoid the `...Insert is not mapped` error? (batch/multiple insert)

Comment: `session.add(query)` -> this is meaningless, `session.add` expects an ORM model instance, but you are passing it the result of a core query.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean with

> The query.values() code below is just a shortened line so as to keep
> things less complicated.

So maybe I am not understanding the issue properly.
At any case the problem here is that you execute the `insert()` and the `values()` separately, while it is meant to be "chained".

Doing something like:

```
query = customers.insert().values(email="test@test.com", name="testy testarosa", phone="+12125551212", address='{"city": "Cities", "street": "123 Main St", "state": "CA", "zip": "10001"}')
```

will work.

Documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TableClause.insert

PS: I did not faced any issues with the JSON field as well. Perhaps something with PG version?

Comment: I meant that I was not inserting all the values (currency, created, etc) and just inserting 'email', 'name', 'phone', & 'address'.